# Send a table as an email in kdb

Tags: kdb

How to send a table and a dictionary as an email in kdb q (without using any api)

I have a table and a dictionary and would like to send it to my email daily in a particular time say 8:00 AM from RDB , 4PM from idb and HDB at the EOD.
Table that i have looks like this:

| Count | Tablename |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | A |
| 8 | B |

email : abc@mail.com,
time : RDB-  8:00 Am , idb - 4pm and hdb everyday

i tried to save the table and send it using system"mail -s "d" mail.com" but couldn't send the table along with it. Please suggest.

Comment: Can you attach other files? This may be a unix/mail question not a kdb one if just sending is the issue.

Comment: Hi @rianoc, there are no files, i am just extracting the rdb data(as a table) and want it to send to my email everyday on a particular time.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the table to txt in the body of the email.

This project has helper functions:

- https://github.com/t-martin/qmail#tables

This video shows it in use:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x4TLphYU46I

```
\l qmail.q
From:"testserver@mydomain.com"
To:"supportteam@gmail.com"
Subject:"Price Alert from application"
Attach: `$":/home/userone/sample.csv"

add:{Body,:$[0h=type x;x;enlist x]};
msg:"The below stocks hit price target";
add .mail.size["15";msg];
info:([] sym:`APA`PDCE`OVV`KYGA;
 price:50.0 70.0 60.0 100.0);
add .mail.ztable info;

.mail.send[From;To;Subject;Body;Attach]
```

Other links:

- https://github.com/AquaQAnalytics/TorQ/blob/master/docs/utilities.md#emailq
- https://code.kx.com/q/ref/doth/